# Bitter orange and scaling

Tags: flavor, recipe-scaling, spices, saison

I'm getting ready to make my first Saison (all grain). This will be the first beer I've made that uses any kind of spice. The recipe I'm using is for a 5g batch. I'll be making a 20g batch. The 5g recipe calls for adding 1oz of Bitter Orange. If I was just scaling the recipe up linearly I'd use 4oz. My gut tells me this might be too much. Should I follow my gut and use only 2oz or should I go with what the recipe calls for?

Comment: When are you adding the bitter orange? In the boil stage, secondary, etc.?

Comment: Do you have a link to the recipe?

Comment: http://beersmithrecipes.com/viewrecipe/2278/walts-hennepin-saison

Comment: Adding the bitter orange to the boil at 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're scaling everything else linearly, you want to do the same with the orange peel, too.

Answer (score 0):

It could be too much, but it depends what it's playing against. If you're also scaling a certain amount of residual sugar, such as from caramel malts, then it could be fine.